# Type Mismatch Using Instr

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-10, packaging, wsh

Hi hope you could help me out with my problem, I have created a package using vbs for IE10 that would check if there are installed hotfix on the computer, if one hotfix/update is missing the script will abort the installation and log the returncode.

I have here a code for checking the hotfix installed on the computer but Im still getting the error type mismatch with using the "Instr"

$----------------------------------
         Checking of installed patches
        ----------------------------------

```
    objShell.run "cmd /c " & chr(34) & "systeminfo >" & strWin & "\Temp\IE10_patches.txt" & chr(34), 0, True

    msgbox strWin & "\Temp\IE10_patches.txt"
    strFile = strWin & "\Temp\IE10_patches.txt"

    WScript.Sleep 5000

    Const ForReading = 1

    Set objFileToRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)


    Do Until objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
            strLine = objFileToRead.ReadLine

            If Len(strLine) > 0 Then 
            strText = Trim(strLine)

            'strLen = Len(strLine)
            'msgbox strLen
            'MSGBOX strLine

            'ctr =  ctr+ 1
            'MSGBOX ctr
```

Getting an error here - > If (InStr(strText, "KB2786081")) > 0 Then

```
        KB2786081_Flag = "True"

        ElseIf (InStr(strText, "KB2731771")) > 0 Then

        KB2731771_Flag = "True"

        ElseIf (InStr(strText, "KB2729094"))  > 0 Then

        KB2729094_Flag = "True"

        ElseIf (InStr(strText, "KB2639308"))  > 0 Then

        KB2639308_Flag = "True"

        ElseIf (InStr(strText, "KB2533623"))  > 0 Then

        KB2533623_Flag = "True"

        ElseIf (InStr(strText, "KB2670838"))  > 0 Then

        KB2670838_Flag = "True"

        End If

    End If

    loop
    objFileToRead.Close
```

Comment: Hmm. Your code works fine for me. The extra parens around the `If` statements aren't needed but they don't hurt anything.

Comment: Hi Bond codes still not working but I found another solution and it works fine. I changed the Instr to InstrRev, i dont know if this will have an issue in the future. Thanks

Comment: That's crazy. `InStrRev()` and `InStr()` both accept two strings so I'm not sure why one would work and not the other. Have you tried specifying all params to `InStr()` -- `InStr(1, strText, "KB1234567", vbTextCompare)`?

Comment: @Bond I may have the answer as I stupidly had this problem today then realised that I had declared a variable `Dim instr` and was assigning a string to it, this obviously had repercussions for anywhere the `InStr()` function was then called. Renaming my variable fixed the problem, I didn't even think about it at the time had `Dim instr, outstr` for input and output string, really silly mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

I may have the solution after having this issue myself today then realising what I had done.

Somewhere in my code I had used `instr` as a variable name which then screws up the `InStr()` function assignment, producing error

> Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A000D)
>   Type mismatch: 'instr'

because `InStr` is now a `String` not a function declaration.

To fix the problem just changed my variable assignment to `Dim in_str`.

Usually you can't do this because `InStr()` is a function if I didn't declare `instr` first and tried to assign it to a String would get this error

> Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01F5)
>   Illegal assignment: 'instr'

This will only happen if you first declare `instr` like this

```vb
'Key is this line without the declaration instr = "test" 
'would fail with an Illegal assignment runtime error.
Dim instr

instr = "test"

'This line will trigger Type Mismatch error if instr has been declared.
If Instr(1, string1, string2) > 0 Then
...
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to find a solution for my own problem, I cleaned up the script a bit and the following works for me on Windows 10. (It's basically the same without the `strWin` and `chr(34)` and a few other minor changes. My computer won't have any of those windows updates, but would still throw the Type Mismatch error if it was an issue):

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run "cmd /c systeminfo > IE10_patches.txt", 0, True

strFile = "IE10_patches.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFileToRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)


Do While Not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFileToRead.ReadLine

        If Len(strLine) > 0 Then 
            strText = Trim(strLine)
            wscript.echo strText
        End If

    If (InStr(strText, "KB2786081")) > 0 Then

        KB2786081_Flag = "True"

    ElseIf (InStr(strText, "KB2731771")) > 0 Then

        KB2731771_Flag = "True"

    ElseIf (InStr(strText, "KB2729094"))  > 0 Then

        KB2729094_Flag = "True"

    ElseIf (InStr(strText, "KB2639308"))  > 0 Then

        KB2639308_Flag = "True"

    ElseIf (InStr(strText, "KB2533623"))  > 0 Then

        KB2533623_Flag = "True"

    ElseIf (InStr(strText, "KB2670838"))  > 0 Then

        KB2670838_Flag = "True"

    End If

Loop
objFileToRead.Close
```

In the midst of messing with this, I remembered the reason for my own `instr` Type Mismatch error. When using `instr`, if you're going to use the Compare (0 = vbBinaryCompare (default) or 1 = vbTextCompare), then you must use the Start option. So in this example (and my mistake), the following:

```
If (InStr(strText, "KB2786081", 1))
```

Needs to be:

```
If (InStr(1, strText, "KB2786081", 1))
```

The `> 0` is not necessary in this case too when simply using instr as a boolean. (It shouldn't be needed in the original OP's script either.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
If (InStr(strText, "KB2786081",1)) > 0 Then
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I will be careful next time.

Comment: Still not working, there might have a problem with test os. Thanks. Im still wondering why Instr giving me type mismatch error though I changed it to InstrRev and works fine.